# How to Flatten Object Underscore with a new Property?

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I'm having an array of this:

```
var arr = [
   {
    name: 'John',
    age: {
        id: 1,
        value: 'less than 19'
      }
   },
   {
    name: 'Doe',
    age: {
         id: 2,
         value: 'more than 19'
      }
   }
]
```

How can I use underscore to flatten the age object in the array. The expected result is:

```
arr == [
       {
        name: 'John',
        age: 'less than 19'
       },
       {
        name: 'Doe',
        age: 'more than 19'
       }
    ];
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var result = arr.map(function(item) {
    return {
        name: item.name,
        age: item.age.value
    };
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var arr = [{
  name: 'John',
  age: {
    id: 1,
    value: 'less than 19'
  }
}, {
  name: 'Doe',
  age: {
    id: 2,
    value: 'more than 19'
  }
}];

var result = arr.map(function(item) {
  return {
    name: item.name,
    age: item.age.value
  };
});

console.log(result);
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

using old style :D

```js
var arr = [
   {
    name: 'John',
    age: {
        id: 1,
        value: 'less than 19'
      }
   },
   {
    name: 'Doe',
    age: {
         id: 2,
         value: 'more than 19'
      }
   }
];

var newArr = [];
arr.forEach(function(item, idx) {
  newArr.push({
    name: item.name,
    age: item.age.value
  });
});

console.log(newArr);
```